# How can I retrieve problem and host name using Zabbix API?

Tags: zabbix

I want to retrieve data from Zabbix API using ZabbixAPI.

So I made API JSON like below.

```
zabbixapi.problem.get(time_from=time_from,
                        time_till=time_till,
                        selectHosts = ["host","name"],
                        sortorder = "DESC",
                        output = "extend",
                        monitored = 1)
```

Result has no host information.
Result is below.

`[{'eventid': '401154', 'source': '0', 'object': '0', 'objectid': '18265', 'clock': '1569375897', 'ns': '887610916', 'r_eventid': '0', 'r_clock': '0', 'r_ns': '0', 'correlationid': '0', 'userid': '0', 'name': 'Optical power is low on port 7', 'acknowledged': '0', 'severity': '3', 'suppressed': '0'}, {'eventid': '401456', 'source': '0', 'object': '0', 'objectid': '30714', 'clock': '1569401534', 'ns': '909385820', 'r_eventid': '0', 'r_clock': '0', 'r_ns': '0', 'correlationid': '0', 'userid': '0', 'name': 'Optical power is low on port 33', 'acknowledged': '0', 'severity': '3', 'suppressed': '0'}]`

I think "selectHosts" does not work.
How can I get problem with host information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/api/reference/problem/get), `problem.get` does not have a `selectHosts` parameter.

Every item of the returned object has a `eventid` value, you can use it in a `event.get` call, which supports `selectHosts`.

Or you can do a single `event.get` call with `selectHosts` plus a filter for `value = 1`, that corresponds to the "Problem" state (see the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/api/reference/event/object) for the event object)

Answer (score 1):

Using curl.

To get problem event ids:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json-rpc" -X POST my_zabbix_url -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","method": "problem.get","params": {},"auth": "my_token","id": 0}'
```

To get hosts based on event id:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json-rpc" -X POST my_zabbix_url -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","method": "event.get","params": {"selectHosts": ["host","name"],"output": "extend","select_acknowledges": "extend","objectids": "my_event_object_id","sortfield": ["clock", "eventid"],"sortorder": "DESC"},"auth": "my_token","id": 0}'
```